# Multiple choice grid HTML in form submission

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I made my own multiple choice grid:

```html
<div style="overflow-x:auto;">
  <table class="w-100">
    <tr>
      <td class="border"></td>
      <td class="border">Yes</td>
      <td class="border">No</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="border">Is red your favorite color?</td>
      <td class="border">
        <div class="custom-control custom-radio"><input type="radio" id="option1" name="row1" value="???" class="custom-control-input">
          <label class="custom-control-label" for="option1"></label></div>
      </td>
      <td class="border">
        <div class="custom-control custom-radio"><input type="radio" id="option2" name="row1" value="???" class="custom-control-input">
          <label class="custom-control-label" for="option2"></label></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

This is in a form and I am running into an issue where I dont know what to set the value so that I can determine which option was pressed and in which row. I am using Django as my backend. Does this make sense. Thanks!!

Comment: Doesn't the `name="row1"` tell you the row based on the number?

Comment: @charlietfl yes. but then how would I know the option that was selected in that row?

Comment: @charlietfl so what would I set the value to?

Comment: Why can't you use numeric values? You can use 1 to n depending on how many on each row. Then you know row and number

Comment: @charlietfl sorry for my confusion, but could you post an answer describing you solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this: Set the values of the radio inputs to yes and no, get the value using `val()` and the row number via the name of the radio input.

```js
$(".custom-control-input").on("change", function() {
  let val = $(this).val();
  let row = $(this).attr("name");
  console.log("value for " + row + ": " + val);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="overflow-x:auto;">
  <table class="w-100">
    <tr>
      <td class="border"></td>
      <td class="border">Yes</td>
      <td class="border">No</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="border">Is red your favorite color?</td>
      <td class="border">
        <div class="custom-control custom-radio"><input type="radio" id="option1" name="row1" value="yes" class="custom-control-input">
          <label class="custom-control-label" for="option1"></label></div>
      </td>
      <td class="border">
        <div class="custom-control custom-radio"><input type="radio" id="option2" name="row1" value="no" class="custom-control-input">
          <label class="custom-control-label" for="option2"></label></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, this does not scale if there are multiple rows. For example, another question called "Is green your favorite color?"

Comment: @NGI How wouldn't that scale if there are multiple rows? You always get the row number and the response. Or do you also want to get the question as reponse?

Comment: Oh, now I understand this approach. One thing: I want to set the value of the radio button since I want to get it in the form submission. How would I do this?

Comment: @NGI You can simply set the values of the radio buttons to "yes" and "no" so you get the value in the form submission.

Comment: Sorry if I am misunderstanding, but what would it look like in the form response?

Comment: @NGI In the form response there would be a name/value pair with the values "row1" and "yes" or "no".

Comment: Ok, this makes sense. I will accept the answer, but have a quick question. What if I were to change it from radios to checkboxes so that you could select more than one option? Thanks!!

Comment: @NGI If you would e.g. have checkboxes with name="color1" value="red" and name="color2" value="blue" and would check both, the form submit would have the name/value pairs "color1" "red" and "color2" "blue".